# Error: [ts] Cannot find name 'React

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

For some specific reasons I need to customize a bit the `Ionic` component: `range`, changing the component class name from `Range` to `CustomRange` (with selector: `custom-range`):

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/range/range.tsx

for that I copy/pasted the files on:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/tree/master/core/src/components/range

inside the directory:

```
/src/components/custom-range
```

Then I imported the module: `CustomRange` into the declarations on file: `app.module.ts`.

Also fixed the references on the `import` statements inside file: `range.tsx` which are fine.

But my problem is that I'm getting errors like:

```
[ts] Cannot find name 'React'.
(property) JSX.IntrinsicElements.slot: JSXElements.SlotAttributes
```

as you can see on the following image:

[image]

Do you have any idea on how can I workaround this?

Thanks!

Comment: `import * as React from 'react';`

Comment: Why is this tagged as Angular?

Comment: are you having angular & react both in your project?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to have [these settings](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/a08b0f950318cadd8e64f5fb493777d7c7826217/core/tsconfig.json#L10-L11) in your `tsconfig.json` if you want to use JSX with Ionic:

```
"jsx": "react",
"jsxFactory": "h",
```

Then as long as you are importing something from `@stencil/core`, you should get the global declaration of `h`, so you should be set.